# Specify number bins when passing sf object to ggmap R

Tags: r, ggmap, r-sf

I have a dataframe object, created by reading in a shape file with sf::read_sf and merged with some pre-existing data with a common geography column:

```
boundaries <- sf::read_sf('./shapefile')

map <- merge(boundaries, data, by.x = "InterZone", 
             by.y = "IntermediateZone2011Code", all.x = FALSE, duplicateGeoms = TRUE)
```

This is then overlaid using ggmap on top of a provider tile obtained with the sf get_map function:

```
myMap <- get_map(location =  c(lon = -2.27, lat = 57.1), zoom = 6,
                 maptype="toner", crop=FALSE, source = 'stamen')

ggmap(myMap) +
  geom_sf(data = map, aes(fill=as.factor(column1)), inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "OrRd") +
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(4326)) + 
  labs(x = 'Longitude', y = 'Latitude', fill = 'column1') + 
  ggtitle('column1')
```

The issue is that this auto creates hundreds of bins.

I have been looking through the documentation but cannot find an additional argument to specify the number of bins. How can I make it clear to breakdown the column by a fixed number of bins and then map this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a reproducible example it is hard to say exactly what is going on, but it looks like you might be converting a continuous variable into a factor with `fill=as.factor(column1)`.

One option is you remove `as.factor` and use `scale_fill_continuous` or some other continuous color scale of your choice.

Another option is to look into `cut`, where you bin continuous data by specifying the number of bins, or the specific start and end points of your bins.

```
# Make n bins
map$data_bin <- cut(map$column, breaks = n )

# Or make specific start and end points for bins
map$data_bin <- cut(map$column, breaks = c(-Inf,50,100,Inf) )
```

Comment: Manually creating a column of bins worked just fine. Thank you for the tip about cut, I'd been using the rbin package previously.